# Power shell executing base on how many files is in the path how to solve this issue?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a code in PowerShell  for file watcher fo my FTP folder and when the code see that there is new file in that folder it will open a batch file that will run a program for my database.

My problem is when i sent multiple files "2 files to be exact" the power shell also execute it twice or more i just need to run it once when the file is already uploaded in the specified folder.

here is my code thank you in advance!

```
$searchPath = "D:\Upload\ftp\"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $searchPath
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action {
  Start-Process "C:\eGaps\Isabela\Automatic-Upload\automata.bat"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event watcher you have in place is designed to look for write to the folder as the occur and you are specifically telling it to take an action on that.

Either set this code as a scheduled task to say run every hour and grab all new files in the folder or change the coded to  look for a certain number of new files before your trigger is called.

The scheduled task is the easiest route IMHO, the below article is an example of how to do the scheduled task approach.

> Scan Folder for Changed/Added Files
>
> Description: Script to check if files have been updated or added in
>   the past 10 minutes, with the expectation that the script will be run
>   as a scheduled task every 10 minutes.
>
> If there is a hit the script will send an email with the changed/added
>   files in the body of the email.
>
> https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1595-scan-folder-for-changed-added-files